# What does this warning indicate in console. I figured it out the first time (I get it from iphoneSimulator->Hardware-SimulateMemoryWarning?

Tags: iphone, memory-management, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios-simulator, audiotoolbox

The app crash only on the iPhone 3G. Is it any audio toolbox library problem?

I get the following warning message which cause the application to crash. What does it say? (I get it from iphoneSimulator->Hardware-SimulateMemoryWarning.)

> 2011-01-22 15:08:34.911 XXXXXXXXX[56011:207] Received simulated memory warning.
>
> 2011-01-22 15:08:38.795  XXXXXXXXX[56011:207] Received simulated memory warning.
>   Detected an attempt to call a symbol in system libraries that is not present on the iPhone:
>
> _Unwind_Resume called from function _ZN15ID3ParserHandleC2EPvPFlS0_mmmPS0_PmE in image AudioToolbox.

I have used the audio ToolBox Framework for playing sounds. Does stoping of it cause this problem?

Comment: hello is there any  system library  function which can not work in i-phone 3g  for FrameWork AudioToolBox ?